# Unit tests pass when I run them from my Intellij IDE but fail when I create the build with Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing

In my Spring Boot 3 and Java17 application, in my unit tests and integration test with Surefire plugin, I access a file called myfile.xml which is located in my project's test/resources/static folder. In my tests I access this file through the request http://lcoalhost:8081/myfile.xml.

When I run all my tests from IntelliJ with the run all test command, they all pass correctly. But if I run the same tests with mvn clean install. I'm getting the error ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8081/myfile.xml": Connection refused. Why if I run them from IntelliJ they all pass correctly but if I run the same tests with Maven, do they fail with the mentioned error?

What is the difference when running them from IntelliJ or from Maven? Maybe I'm forgetting something in my Maven configuration?

I am using these annotations

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)  
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = { "server.port=8080" }) 
@DirtiesContext
```

And this maven configuration on my pom.xml

```
 <plugin>                 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
</plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Xmx1024m -noverify</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The configuration uses `server.port=8080` while the error message shows port 8081?

Comment: often maven in the commandline might be using a differen java version which could play a role - check java version maven is using with `mvn -version`

Comment: Thanks @JAsgarov , I just checked and is using the java17 version,  that is right

Comment: @khmarbaise when I run from intellij with current configuration it works ok.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I don't understand why it works with 8081 if I have specified 8080 in the configuration.